# Access SharePoint Data on Linux

Tags: linux, client, cross-platform

Is there a way to get the SharePoint 2013 data from Lists into Linux ? I am looking forward to create Linux scripts which could pull data from SharePoint and work accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SharePoint exposes web API that is independent of client's OS. You can consume SOAP web services and REST APIs from Linux.

The idea is that you need HTTP POST requests with proper SOAP Envelope messages in the body for [SOAP web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193051%28v=office.15%29.aspx) such as /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx and HTTP GET,PUT,POST,DELETE requests for the [REST endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569%28v=office.15%29.aspx) such as /_vti_bin/Client.svc and /_api.

I hope you'll manage to [find](https://www.google.ru/search?q=how%20to%20consume%20sharepoint%20from%20linux) a good how-to given this introductory information.

Comment: I've updated the anwser.

Comment: In essence, Linux can run Node.js for example, and you can use any JavaScript sample or library that builds SOAP/REST queries - there are lots available.